# Upgrading the PSP browser

Tags: psp

The built in browser with the PSP is awful. It has 3 hopeless modes of screen scaling, poor JavaScript support and constantly runs out of memory. Even mediocre mobile phones trounce it.

There's so much potential in the little guy, are there any methods to getting a stable and useful web browser on the PSP?

I'm using a launch model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without unlocking your device, which might not be legal in your area.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but I guess its the only one! Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

This might be a bit late but if go on pspinstaller10 somones built a new psp browser it looks the same but it works great